# DiskShadow dsh script spaces end of line

Tags: windows, backup

I've been reading some documentation about Diskshadow and made the following dsh script as an example.
Somehow on execution every line needs an extra space at the end, is there someone that can tell me why this is?

```
#Diskshadow script file
set verbose on
set context persistent nowriters
begin backup
add volume c: alias systemvolumeshadow
create
expose %systemvolumeshadow% Z:
end backup
#End of script
```

if i do not add the spaces on each line i get the following errors:

```
Microsoft DiskShadow version 1.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation
On computer:  DC01,  7/7/2020 5:27:03 PM

-> #Diskshadow script fil
-> set verbose O

SET VERBOSE { ON | OFF }
```